# Discord.js snekfetch body undefined problem

Tags: javascript, discord

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    const snekfetch = require("snekfetch")
    const client = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: false});
    //const CSGO = require("csgo-api"); // Import the npm package.
    //const jb = new CSGO.Server('185.198.75.5', '27015') // Set the IP with port.
    
    var prefix2 = "!"
    
    client.on('ready', async ()=> {
        snekfetch.get("http://query.li/api/csgo/185.198.75.5/27015").then(r => console.log(r.body.game.players.name));
        //jb.getOnlinePlayers().then(data => console.log(data)) // Get & log the data
   });
```

Hello friends, I'm trying to print the players section on http://query.li/api/csgo/185.198.75.5/27015 to message.channel.send but it gives undefined can you help me?
I'm using Google Translate sorry my English so bad :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the body of the result. But it is null. Your result contains these children: game, whois, status, banner_url, and cached.

And also, your players are an array. So you should select an index to console.log().

Try this:

```
    snekfetch.get("http://query.li/api/csgo/185.198.75.5/27015").then(r => console.log(r.game.players[0].name));
```

You can use this [web site](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to beautify your response JSON.

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want to print the names of all players then you can use a foreach() loop for players. Like this:

```
  snekfetch.get("http://query.li/api/csgo/185.198.75.5/27015").then(r => {
    r.game.players.forEach(player => {
      console.log(player.name)
    });
   }
  );
```

Comment: thats work but i print all players name,score,duration

Comment: Ok, you can look at the editing part of my answer. I improved it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. How can I print duration in h:m:s ?

Comment: This is about another question. You can ask a new question. Now, you should accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: Well, so be it: D but I have one more problem with this question, when I can send all of the data on the site in one order, it sends them in order. How can I send them all in one?